Propagation of uncertainties for high signal-to-noise ratio measurements
I am writing mass spectrometry data reduction software which calculates 4He volumes, and I have some questions about the propagation of uncertainties.
The system in question measures helium volumes by comparing the ratio of the gas in a known 4He standard with a 3He spike, to the ratio of 4He gas in the unknown with a 3He spike:
final_result = Q_vol * sample_ratio / Q_ratio

where:

Q_vol is the volume of 4He in the standard
x_ratio is the ratio of mass 4 to mass 3 from the raw mass spec data

This system also measures blanks for both the sample and standards, wherein we are effectively measuring nothing -- that is, there is a small amount of 4He in the 3He spike, but the amount is just barely above the baseline so the signal-to-noise ratio on these is very high. The standard deviation of the 4He in these blank measurements is therefore also high (~10-20%) relative to a stable signal like the standards (<0.35%) or sample gas. On occasion, these blanks can stray into the negative range (why the mass spec reports negative data is beyond me...), yielding %SD ~ 80%.
Incorporating blanks brings the full equation to:
final_result = Q_vol * (sample_ratio - sample_blank_ratio) / (Q_ratio - Q_blank_ratio)

When propagating the error on my results,
final_error = sqrt(Q_vol_err^2 + sample_ratio_err^2 + sample_blank_ratio_err^2 + Q_ratio_err^2 + Q_blank_ratio_err^2)

the high standard deviation of the blanks ends up contributing a significant amount of error: for example, errors on final results are about 2% without the blank uncertainty, and 20% with.
While I understand that adding a high-error term also adds error to the final calculation, having the error on the blanks completely dominate the uncertainty by increasing it an entire order of magnitude, as opposed to things like the fit of the raw data or the distribution of Q ratios dominating the uncertainty, feels intrinsically wrong. These uncertainties shouldn't be given the same weight, however, I'm not sure how to go about 'fairly and accurately' (that is, in a scientifically/statistically meaningful way) weighting these data.
How would you treat such data if you were in my shoes?
EDIT: I've tried a few new equations
$$
\sigma_f =  \left(\frac{(R_{\text{s}} - R_{\text{sb}})}{(R_{\text{Q}} - R_{\text{Qb}})} \sigma_{Q_{\text{vol}}}\right)^2 +
\left(Q_{\text{vol}} \frac{1}{(R_{\text{Q}} - R_{\text{Qb}})} \sigma_{R_{\text{s}}}\right)^2 +
\left(- Q_{\text{vol}} \frac{1}{(R_{\text{Q}} - R_{\text{Qb}})} \sigma_{R_{\text{sb}}}\right)^2 +
\left(- Q_{\text{vol}} \frac{(R_{\text{s}} - R_{\text{sb}})}{(R_{\text{Q}} - R_{\text{Qb}})^2} \sigma_{R_{\text{Q}}}\right)^2 +
\left(Q_{\text{vol}} \frac{(R_{\text{s}} - R_{\text{sb}})}{(R_{\text{Q}} - R_{\text{Qb}})^2} \sigma_{R_{\text{Qb}}}\right)^2
$$
where

R means 4 amu / 3 amu ratio
subscript Q means standard, s means sample, and b means blank
sigma means raw uncertainty

This produces larger uncertainties for small He volumes, and smaller errors for large 4He volumes, which makes sense and the uncertainties are at a reasonable level.
